# Using only OC0B pin to generate tone

Tags: avr, atmega, atmel

I'm trying to generate tone with couple configurable frequencies on pin OC0B of Atmega328, Fast-PWM mode.

```
TCCR0A  |= _BV(WGM01) | _BV(WGM00); 
TCCR0B  |= _BV(WGM02);

TCCR0A  |= _BV(COM0B1) | _BV(COM0B0); 
TCCR0B  |= _BV(CS01) | _BV(CS00); 

OCR0A   = 100;
```

I set to Fast PWM(7), then prescaler 64, OC0A is disconnected and OC0B is connected in inverting mode. There is no tone on OC0B.

I was only able to generate tone on OC0A when I set COM0A0 to 1. But I only need to generate tone on OC0B.

So there are two questions.
1. How can I generate tone on OC0B pin?
2. While tone is generated on OC0B, can I use OC0A as GPIO pin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly relevant: The [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8161.pdf) p.102 has this to say:

Setting the COM0A1:0 bits to one allows the OC0A pin to toggle on Compare Matches if the WGM02 bit is set. This option is not available for the OC0B pin (see Table 14-6 on page 107).

Might be the issue? (though I haven't looked at Table 14.6)

Comment: Only *toggle* action will generate frequency on OC0B pin? Datasheet says "Clear OC0A on Compare Match, set OC0A at BOTTOM", this means it will set and clear on certain conditions. Also the question whether both A and B pins are synced or I can use A as GPIO is still open...

Comment: Maybe not relevant then. The question doesn't show a value for OCR0B : what happens when it is < OCR0A, say 50?

Comment: nothing at all.